# p:tree TreeNode background-color

Tags: css, primefaces, css-specificity

I have the following scenario:
I want to build a website using PrimeFaces. The following section is rendered white, but it should be red.

```
        <p:tree value="#{index.root}" var="node" style="width: 100%">
            <p:treeNode type="FAIL" styleClass="fail">
                <span style="cursor: pointer;"
                    onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.click();"> <h:outputText
                        value="#{node}" /> <h:commandButton value="Mark as handled" />
                </span>
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>
```

index.css

```
.fail {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Investigating the treeNode in Firefox Inspector I see the following structure

[image: firefoxinspector]

If I uncheck the background-color: transparent from .ui-tree .ui-tree-node section, the tree is rendered red (as it should be).

Does anybody know why the browser exhibit this behavior and how I can fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you put `background-color: #F00 !important;`? Otherwise I think you'll have to set the css for the exact same class. `.ui-tree .ui-treenode`.

Comment: @DaMaGeX It seems to work with background-color: #F00 !important; but I read that using !important is not recommended. I cannot use the second approach because I want some tree nodes to have different colors.

Comment: Well, then you either edit the source of Primefaces or just put !important. If you are sure that no one else is going to build another mod on top of it, then it's fine. Just keep it in mind for yourself to prevent hours of searching why things don't change. Other than that !important is fine.

Comment: Another thing that came to my mind is trying `.ui-tree .ui-treenode.fail`. Not sure if this will work without !important tho.

Comment: @DaMaGeX Your last suggestion worked without !important. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've worked out in the comments below the question, use

```
.ui-tree .ui-treenode.fail
```

to overwrite the Primeface CSS rules. This is because the selector is more specific this way. As Tim Schoch said in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, that `.fail` is less specific then `.ui-tree .ui-tree-node`.
Check https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ and https://specificity.keegan.st/ to see how css specificity works.